# IntelliJ - switching between multiple git local branches

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ on a project with multiple modules. I have started a big refactoring and created local branches for 3 modules. Each branch has the same name. Currently, I have to checkout each of them (for each module, that is). Is there a way to do a global checkout? Or to create a single branch for all modules?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just go to Settings | Version Control | Git and select "Control branches from different roots synchronously", and all operations on branches (VCS -> Git -> Branches) will be performed for 3 repositories at once.

See details in this [blogpost](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2012/08/git-branches-for-multi-root-projects/).

Also make sure that all 3 modules are correctly registered in the roots table in Settings | Version Control.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot. When following your steps, the branch is actually listed in "Common local branches".

Comment: for 2018 this is now `Preferences > Version Control > Git > Execute branch operations on all roots`

Comment: for 2020 this is now `Preferences > Version Control`, click on `Unregistered roots` and press `+` to add to `Directory` list.